# Order flat structure into tree knowing only parents

Tags: php, algorithm, tree

Given the following structure of arrays:

```
array(
   55 => array(
       'ident' => 'test 1',
       'depth' => 1,
   ),
   77 => array(
       'parent_id' => 55,
       'ident' => 'test 2',
       'depth' => 2,
   )
);
```

Is there a general algorithm that can be used to turn that into a nested tree?

i.e.

```
array(
   55 => array(
       'ident' => 'test 1',
       'depth' => 1,
       'children' => array(
            77 => array(
                'parent_id' => 55,
                'ident' => 'test 2',
                'depth' => 2,
           )
       )
   )
);
```

The example i have provided is simplified, the real case includes hundreds of nodes + a depth of up to 15.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd use this as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975585/search-for-a-key-in-an-array-recursivly

Comment: There are a lot of these sort of questions on the site, try looking for "php construct hierarchical" or something like that, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060955/easiest-way-to-build-a-tree-from-a-list-of-ancestors/1060993#1060993

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv just to note; what you linked to has a horrible complexity (at least when it's also feasible in O(n) => see my answer below)

Comment: I'd argue that you first have to try it to know this issue exists, don't you think? A recursive solution is perfectly acceptable for "hundreds of nodes".

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv recursively is actually `O(n^2)` Imagine 700 nodes… recursively _"only"_ ±250k iterations (in average) [plus the fact that function calls are also relatively slow generally] or just 700 iterations in total for foreach with references… I think at this point it begins to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with references helps a lot. This way you can still append to the children even if they're already inserted.

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$sub) {
    if (isset($sub['parent_id'])) {
        $array[$sub['parent_id']]['children'][$key] = &$sub;
    }
}
unset($sub); // unset the reference to make sure to not overwrite it later...

// now remove the entries with parents
foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
    if (isset($sub['parent_id'])) { 
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Some demo for this: http://3v4l.org/D6l6U#v500

Comment: I'm probably the only one who would prefer to avoid PHP references like the plague.. never the less, Interesting answer.

Comment: @MackieeE Hell, references are awesome. Without them, half of recursive stuff would be impossible.

Comment: @MackieeE yeah; I'd also try to avoid them, but that is actually a very valid use case. Because I just cannot imagine other solutions which would run in O(n) and use no references…

Comment: @MackieeE: I think most people hate references in PHP - can cause a hell of a mess.  But bwoebi is right about the performance, without them either the memory or the processing time would fly upwards, having to store paths, etc.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a play with them tonight =] thank you, insightful! I suppose it's the fact that I feel most referencing in PHP feels very, behind the scenes, reading it initially doesn't seem to click straight away - besides +1 on the answer & demo!